# Bash import args and search directories issue

Tags: bash

Stuck trying to search if a file exists in a directory that's name has been imported from another txt file and if it exists to create a new one.

```
file="/home/user/data.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
    # display $line or do something with $line
    echo "$line"
    sudo mkdir -p /home/"$line"

    if [ -e "$line".txt]
    then
        echo "ok backup file exists"
    else
        echo "no backup file - one created"
        touch  ../home/"$line"/"$line".txt
    fi
```

errors are that the touch is not creating new file. Have created the input `$line` folders

Comment: You need a space before `]`.

Comment: You're not testing whether the file exists in the `/home/$line` directory.

Comment: Why do you create the directory in `/home`, but then touch the file in `../home`?

Comment: Add a `done` to your code.